# Create a polygon around each point in geojson from geojson

Tags: javascript, leaflet, maps, mapbox, geojson

Creating a map similar to the one found here:
https://www.plantmaps.com/interactive-california-2012-usda-plant-zone-hardiness-map.php

Have all the data needed.
Create polygons around each one without distance inbetween. No overlapping or similar.

Drawing it all by hand on geojson.io, seems impossible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to create polygons around each [point] and make sure there is no distance between them.

What you're describing here is a [tessellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tessellation). Depending on your data, you might opt for a regular tessellation (i.e. creating a grid of squares or hexagons, paying a modicum of attention to the units of your coordinate system) or the well-known-among-GIS-people [Voronoi tessellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram). Note that a Voronoi tessellation created over a regular grid of points will result in a regular grid of polygons.

There are plenty of tools for Voronoi tessellations. For javascript and GeoJSON, my tool of choice would be [turf.js's voronoi module](http://turfjs.org/docs/#voronoi).

Comment: thank you for the answer, i'm trying it out as we speak. I will give you notice in a few hours

Comment: I keep getting an error " turf.voronoi is not a function
    at Object"   do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong?https://jsfiddle.net/jw3vx4eg/1/ Kind regards

Comment: thanks so much for your detailed answer. Turf documentation lacks that kind of explanations. For example that note was all money in the world: _Voronoi tessellation created over a regular grid of points will result in a regular grid of polygons._

Answer (score 1):

Here are some things to consider:

- creating polygon from a point is simple enough.  For example you use the **point** as the center of a regular polygon and devide 2PI by the number of sides and step through the points to create the polygon.  But, what is the radius?  That depends on the projection you are using.  I happen to use [OpenLayers](https://openlayers.org/) and really like this map control.  It's default projection it EPSG:3857.  So, the coordinates are already in **meters** - so easy.  But if your points are in long/lat then you have to do some math.  it may be easier to transform to a different projection temporarily.  An opensource library that is really nice for gis calculations if you need one is [Turf](http://turfjs.org/).
- You mentioned also about having non-overlapping polygons?  Well, in this case you will have a lot of gaps if you use regular polygons.  To have non-overlapping polygons with, as you put it **no distance between them** is an interesting constraint.  Now you are dealing with different shaped polygons.  And an algorithm for handling that is pretty intense.  I know that MapInfo GIS has a feature for adjusting polygons to be non-overlapping.  But, in a JavaScript environment with GeoJSON, you are probably talking about server side logic for this.
- That map you are looking at looks like it is using [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/) with [svg overlays](https://github.com/teralytics/Leaflet.D3SvgOverlay).